# Assign row values from one object to another object as columns or fields

Tags: apex, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-soql, dynamic-apex, field-mapping

I have row values as dates in one object, i.e dates within a given year. I have a second object with field names as Day1__c, Day2__c and so on till Day366__c. I want to assign the dates to the fields in the 2nd object.

Example, if the date in the first object is 2018-01-01 I want to assign a value to field Day1__c in the second object and if the date is 2018-12-31 I want to assign a value to Day365__c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the `dayOfYear()` method of [Date class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) can help you to achieve this requirement.

As per Salesforce it "Returns the day-of-year component of a Date." First, you have to get this number (suppose 294) based on the Date from the first object and you can relate the corresponding field in the second object as Day294__c.

```
date myDate = date.newInstance(1998, 10, 21);
Integer day = myDate.dayOfYear();
system.assertEquals(294, day);
```

Comment: Thansk Saroj. That was helpful.